# Highchart - always show crosshair

Tags: highcharts

Does anyone know how to show the crosshairs programmatically?

When I try to use chart.tooltip.refresh(point), I am able to successfully show the tooltip but no the crosshair. I can only see the crosshair when I hover near the data point.

Also, is it possible to keep the crosshair from disappearing when you hover out of the chart area?

A jsfiddle would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "always show"? Always show crosshair for all points? A single point? I think in that maybe plotlines is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can catch mouseOver event and add / update plotLines.

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {
                        var chart = this.series.chart;


                        var x = this.x,
                            y = this.y;
                        if (chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands.length > 0) {
                            chart.xAxis[0].update({
                                plotLines: [{
                                    id: 'xPlotLine',
                                    value: x,
                                    width: 1,
                                    color: '#C0C0C0'
                                }]
                            });

                            chart.yAxis[0].update({
                                plotLines: [{
                                    id: 'yPlotLine',
                                    value: y,
                                    width: 1,
                                    color: '#C0C0C0'
                                }]
                            });
                        } else {
                            chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
                                id: 'xPlotLine',
                                value: x,
                                width: 1,
                                color: '#C0C0C0'
                            });

                            chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
                                id: 'yPlotLine',
                                value: y,
                                width: 1,
                                color: '#C0C0C0'
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/792rX/3/

Answer (score 2):

To "always show crosshair" you may want to use plotlines. If for only a single static point you could add it in the options for your chart. To make it appear exactly like the standard grid lines it would look something like this:

```js
plotLines: [{
    value: 3,
    width: 1,
    color: '#C0C0C0'
}]
```

And would be added with correct `value` for both `xAxis` and `yAxis`. See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/792rX/).

To be a bit more flexible and do it after rendering your chart, you could do something like this:

```js
function addCrosshair(x,y) {
    chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
        id: 'xPlotLine'+x,
        value: x,
        width: 1,
        color: '#C0C0C0'
    });

    chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
        id: 'yPlotLine'+y,
        value: y,
        width: 1,
        color: '#C0C0C0'
    });
}

function removeCrosshair(x,y) {
    chart.xAxis[0].removePlotLine('xPlotLine'+x);
    chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('yPlotLine'+y);
}
```

Which utilizes the [`Axis.addPlotLine`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine) and [`Axis.removePlotLine`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.removePlotLine) to manage plotlines after render time. See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/792rX/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add crosshair style like this:

```
// Always show crosshair after tooltip hide event
.highcharts-crosshair {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```